# CoreData fetch return a nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Why when I print myData array in contains at first position all my valueForKey in nil, like this

```
  func fetchFavorites(){

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Favoritos")

    do {
        let result = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in result {

            if let Fid = managedObject.valueForKey("place_favorite_id"), 
            desc_place = managedObject.valueForKey("desc_place"), 
            place_name = managedObject.valueForKey("place_name"),
            lat = managedObject.valueForKey("latitude"),
            lon = managedObject.valueForKey("longitude") {

                print("\(Fid) \(desc_place) \(place_name) \(lat) \(lon)")
                Place_Id.append(Fid as! String)

            }

        }
        myData = result

    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
}
```

Printed myData Array

```
    Array[<RivosTaxi.Favoritos: 0x7fb46ff5ac80> (entity: Favoritos; id: 0xd00000000024000e <x-coredata://82CCF746-275D-4FC6-9C5C-EFD1EDED2F21/Favoritos/p9> ; data: {
"desc_place" = nil;
latitude = nil;
longitude = nil;
"place_favorite_id" = nil;
"place_name" = nil;

    }), <RivosTaxi.Favoritos: 0x7fb46ff5af80> (entity: Favoritos; id: 0xd00000000028000e <x-coredata://82CCF746-275D-4FC6-9C5C-EFD1EDED2F21/Favoritos/p10> ; data: {
"desc_place" = "";
latitude = "24.822311";
longitude = "-107.4240634";
"place_favorite_id" = 94;
"place_name" = "Otro mad";
```

That is what I dont understand, the first values are all nil, and I only have 1 row of data at my sqlite, not two

This is how y save it to Favoritos Entity

```
    func FavoritosSave(){

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Favoritos", inManagedObjectContext: moc)



    entity.setValue(place_name, forKey: "place_name")
    entity.setValue(place_favorite, forKey: "place_favorite_id")
    entity.setValue(desc_place, forKey: "desc_place")
    entity.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    entity.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")

    // we save our entity
    do {
        try moc.save()


    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code where you create and save to CoreData

Answer (score 2):

Your fetch request is written to return all instances with entity name of "Favoritos". That search result shows that you've created two.

An explanation for only seeing one row could be that your MOC hasn't been saved. But going dumpster diving in Core Data's SQLite file is a recipe for frustration. Use the documented APIs.

You should add a call to `fetchFavoritos()` as the first line of your save() function, to see what's there before you create the Favoritos instance.